# For Comprehension Return type

Tags: scala, list, for-loop, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I am trying to return Future[Vector[String]] from for comprehension but I am getting Future[Nothing] as my return type. How to convert Future[Nothing] return type to Future[Vector[String]]?
Here is the code snippet:

```
def findProjectId(projectName: String, userId: String): Future[Nothing] = {
    for {
      projectIds <- dBService.fetchProjectIdByProjectName(projectName) // projectIds is Vector[String]
      pid <- projectIds
      projectId <- dBService.filterProjectId(pid, userId) // ProjectId is Vector[String]
      if projectId.nonEmpty
    } yield {
      projectId map {
        projectid =>
          dBService.fetchRoleId map { // fetchRoleId returns Future[Vector[String]]
            case Vector(rid) => dBService.fetchCollaborator(projectid, rid) map { // fetchCollaborator returns Future[Vector[String]]
              listOfcollabs =>
                if (listOfcollabs.nonEmpty) {
                  listOfcollabs ++ Vector(userId)
                }
                else {
                  Vector(userId)
                }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Signatures of dbService methods are:

```
  def checkCollaboratorOrAdmin(userId: String, projectId: String, roleId: String): Future[Vector[String]] = {
    dbComponent.db.run(checkAdminOrCollab(roleId))
  }

  def fetchRoleId: Future[Vector[String]] = {
    dbComponent.db.run(fetchRole)
  }

  def fetchCollaborator(roleId: String, projectId: String): Future[Vector[String]] = {
    dbComponent.db.run(fetchCollaborators(roleId, projectId))
  }

  def fetchProjectIdByProjectName(projectName: String) = {
    dbComponent.db.run(fetchProjectId(projectName))
  }

  def filterProjectId(projectId: String, userId: String) = {
    dbComponent.db.run(filterProjectIdByUserId(projectId, userId))
  }
```

These methods in turn call:

```
  def fetchRoleId(userId: String, projectId: String): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select distinct(role_id) from project_user_role where user_id=$userId and project_id=$projectId""".as[String]
  }

  def checkAdminOrCollab(roleId: String): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select role_id from roles where role_id=$roleId and role_name="collaborator" """.as[String]
  }

  def fetchRole(): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select role_id from roles where role_name="collaborator"""".as[String]
  }

  def fetchCollaborators(roleId: String, projectId: String): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select user_id from project_user_role where roleId=$roleId and project_id=$projectId""".as[String]
  }

  def fetchProjectId(projectName: String): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select project_id from projects where project_name=$projectName""".as[String]
  }

  def filterProjectIdByUserId(projectId: String, userId: String): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[String], String, Effect] = {
    sql"""select project_id from project_user_role where project_id=$projectId and user_id=$userId""".as[String]
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the signatures of the dBService methods? Specifically the full return type of each?

Comment: And also put all your fetches inside for-comprehension for better readability.

Comment: @AssafMendelson I have added signatures of the DB service methods

Comment: @jyoti can you add return types to signatures for fetchProjectIdByProjectName and filterProjectId?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that the `Future[Nothing]` comes from IntelliJ hints, rather than the compiler itself. The compiler gives a couple of errors, the first coming from this line:

```
pid <- projectIds
```

This is the error I get:

> Test.scala:47:13: type mismatch;
>
> [error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
>
> [error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]

The problem is that the `for` expression is trying to build a value of type `Future[_]` using using `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` calls. (The collection type of a `for` is the collection type of the first expression in the `for`). `flatMap` on `Future` takes a `Future` and turns `Future[Future[_]]` into `Future[_]`. However you are giving it a `Vector` which is not supported.

I'm also unsure of the broader logic because you have two nested `Vectors` (projectIds and listOfCollabs) but no mechanism for flattening this into a single vector.

You probably want to look at using `Future.traverse` or `Future.sequence` to turn lists of `Future` into `Future[List]`.

It would also make sense to break this down into some named functions to make the code more comprehensible and give a better chance of isolating the problem.

#### Update

This code will call the appropriate functions and return the results. The return type is `Future[Vector[Vector[Vector[String]]]]` because each `dBService` call returns `Future[Vector[String]]` so you get nested `Vector`s. It is not clear from the question how to flatten this into the result you want, but it should be straightforward. (The result of the last call is flattened by the `case` statement which is why there 4 `dBService` calls but only 3 nested `Vectors` )

```
def findProjectId(projectName: String, userId: String): Future[Vector[Vector[Vector[String]]]] = {
  dBService.fetchProjectIdByProjectName(projectName).flatMap { projectIds =>
    Future.traverse(projectIds) { pid =>
      dBService.filterProjectId(pid, userId).flatMap { projectId =>
        Future.traverse(projectId) { projectid =>
          dBService.fetchRoleId.flatMap { // fetchRoleId returns Future[Vector[String]]
            case Vector(rid) =>
              dBService.fetchCollaborator(projectid, rid) map { // fetchCollaborator returns Future[Vector[String]]
                _ ++ Vector(userId)
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It may be that you can just take the first element of some of these `Vectors` which would simplify the code.

`Future.traverse(collection)(f)` is equivalent to `Future.sequence(collection.map(f))` but gives better layout and may be more efficient.